# Como puedo editar el style css de un child theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Busco en el Cpanel el archivo que debo editar pero solo me aparece información, no hay líneas de código para editar.

Lo que busco es editar los colores que trae el theme electro de WordPress, En su panel trae una opción para editar los colores con elecciones predeterminadas pero busco poner un color exacto.

Comment: Solo necesitas seleccionar el archivo y, en la parte de arriba, aparecerá un botón para editar. Tutorial: https://help.wnpower.com/hc/es/articles/360029483312-Utilizando-el-Administrador-de-Archivos-de-cPanel

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que crees primero el tema hijo con un plugin como Chil Theme Configurator, si eres principiante en el mundo del WordPress o en su defecto te recomiendo que uses el [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) y crees tu tema hijo desde 0, una vez creado lo actives y despues lo abras directamente con el editor de tema de WordPress, los temas hijos se guardan en wp-content/themes/el-nombre-de-tu-tema y si todo va bien deberias de ver el archvio style.css en la raiz de la carpeta de tu proyecto.